# Why does my delete button not remove an item from my repository?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use this.remove() in order to remove an item from a JPA repository, but for some reason it does not work. Below is the code from the JavaScript page that contains the delete button, with the specific line in bold:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/TaskList.css';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Container, Table } from 'reactstrap';
import Select from "react-select/creatable";
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class TaskList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {tasks: [], isLoading: true};
        this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/tasks')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({tasks: data, isLoading: false}));
    }

    async remove(id) {
        await fetch(`/tasks/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(() => {
            let updatedTasks = [...this.state.tasks].filter(i => i.id !== id);
            this.setState({tasks: updatedTasks});
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {tasks, isLoading} = this.state;

        //if waiting for tasks to fetch
        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading...</p>;
        }

        //options for the sort select menu
        const options = [
            {value: 'priority', label: 'Priority'},
            {value: 'type', label: 'Type'},
            {value: 'class', label: 'Class'},
            {value: 'date', label: 'Due Date'}
        ]

        //method to be called when a new sort selection is made
        const handleSortSelectChange = (option) => {
            let updatedTasks;
            switch (option.value) {
                case 'priority':
                    updatedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => b.priority - a.priority);
                    break;
                case 'date':
                    updatedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => a.dueDate - b.dueDate);
                    break;
                case 'class':
                    //TODO implement sort by class
                    console.log('Sort by class');
                    updatedTasks = tasks;
                    break;
                case 'type':
                    updatedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => b.typeID - a.typeID);
                    break;
                default:
                    updatedTasks = tasks.sort((a, b) => a.dueDate - b.dueDate);
            }

            this.setState({tasks: updatedTasks});
        }

        //component that maps all tasks to <tr> elements
        const taskList = tasks.map(task => {
            const date = task.dueDate;

            return (
                <tr key={task.id} onClick={"/tasks/" + task.id}>
                <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}><a href={"/tasks/" + task.id}>{task.name}</a></td>
                <td className='task-priority'>{getPriorityString(task.priority)}</td>
                <td>{task.courseID}</td>
                <td>{task.type}</td>
                <td>{date}</td>
                <td>
                   ** <ButtonGroup>
                        <Button size="sm" color="danger" onClick={() => this.remove(task.id)}>Delete</Button>**
                    </ButtonGroup>
                </td>
            </tr>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <AppNavbar/>
                <Container fluid>
                    <h3 className='m-2'>Tasks</h3>
                    <div id="list-top" className="m-2">
                        <Button color="success" tag={Link} to="/tasks/new">Add Task</Button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="list-sort" className="m-2">
                        <Select className='m-2' options={options} onChange={handleSortSelectChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="list-top" className="m-2">
                        <h5 className='m-2'>Sort By</h5>
                    </div>
                    <Table className="m-2">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="30%">Name</th>
                            <th width="10%">Priority</th>
                            <th width="20%">Class</th>
                            <th width="10%">Type</th>
                            <th width="20%">Due Date</th>
                            <th width="10%"></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {taskList}
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function getPriorityString(priority) {
    let result = "";
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < priority; i++) {
        result += "!";
    }
    return result;
}

export default TaskList;
```

I've tried looking around online and at other forums to see if I am doing something wrong, but everything I have found says that this should work. Everything else works within the program, so I'm at a loss as to why this specific function does not.

Comment: Well, you don't have any error handling. Are there any errors in the console? What happens if the API call fails? What happens if the id doesn't exist, or the types don't match? Side note: why are you mixing `await` with `.then`?

Comment: There are no errors that get thrown in the console, and as for the id/type issues, the button appears for each individual item on a page that is displayed, so it is never an issue if the id doesn't exist or the type doesn't match.